# ldap_add(): Add: Referral

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to add the user to my LDAP server. But I'm getting the below error.

```
PHP Warning:  ldap_add(): Add: Referral

Code:
$ds = ldap_connect("HOST","PORT"); 
if ($ds) {
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$bind = ldap_bind($ds, "adminusername", "Passwrd");
echo $bind;
// prepare data
$base_dn = 'CN=Manus Test,OU=UserAccounts,DC=rk.com,DC=rk';
$info["givenName"]="manu";
$info["sn"]="Manu";
$info["uid"]="manus";
$info["homeDirectory"]="/home/";
$info["mail"]="manus@gmail.com";
$info["displayName"]= "Jdkd sjs";
$info["cn"] ="Manus Test";
//$info["userPassword"]=>user_hash;
$info["objectclass"][0] = "top";
$info["objectclass"][1] = "person";
$info["objectclass"][2] = "inetOrgPerson";
$info["objectclass"][3] = "organizationalPerson";

// add data to directory
$r = ldap_add($ds, $base_dn, $info);
echo "Bind result is " . $r . "<br />";
```

Please let me know any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referrals can be returned if you are talking to a slave LDAP server (essentially a read-only copy of the directory). If you know you are talking to a server hosting a writable copy of the replica, referrals are also returned when the DN base is not something hosted by that server.

Looking at the code above, "DC=rk.com,DC=rk" is unusual. I generally see the "domain" components broken out so rk.com becomes "dc=rk,dc=com". Use an ldap browser to verify the pattern for fully qualified DNs in your directory.

Comment: The second point is useful. My problem got resolved. Thank you :)